# How to set base-uri for the Struts 2 CSP Interceptor?

Tags: struts2, struts

Version 6 of Struts introduced the [Content Security Policy interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/csp-interceptor) which is in the default stack. It has a nonce-based attribute which allows putting scripts and links via the Struts `<s:script>` and `<s:link>` tag, which is quite nice.

However, I do want to be able to set the `base-uri` value to the standard one for my site. I do not see an easy way to do this. There is a `CSPSettings` class which allows setting things on a per-action basis -- I'd prefer global -- but even there, it doesn't seem to do what I want. You can change from report-only to enforced, and change where reports are sent -- and that seems to be it.

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem. What is the `base-uri`?

Comment: It is a well-known Content Security Policy value. I've engaged with the developers of the framework and am working on a pull request to solve this issue. I will post a solution when done.